# Instamojo light checkout url is not loading in the cordova inappbrowser for android 4.4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, instamojo

I have developed the ionic project in the version 1.3.3. Now I have upgraded the version to 2.0.0 and also dependencies too upgraded to the higher version. Now I was unable to do payment via cordova inappbrowser plugin in android 4.4 and its show the white blank screen. I can do the payment in android version 5 and above. I found the launch.json attributes like version,configurations,type,request are Grey in color and it looks like those attributes are disabled. I have installed the cordova tools and cordova dev essentials extension.

And my environment details:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.10
Node Version: v6.0.0
Cordova android version: 6.1.2
Android studio version: 3.1
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser: 1.7.1

Why I was unable to do the payment in android 4.4 and is the cordova was disabled?